# Azure - Erro 401

Tags: microsoft-azure, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando fazer um post para inserir um registro num WebAPI hospedado na azure.

https://acelerasp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/Ocorrencia/InserirOcorrencia

Estou utilizando POSTMAN para efetuar os testes, passando os parametros via form-data.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao testar em localhost, funciona corretamenteo.

Mas ao tentar acessar pela azure, recebo esta mensagem de erro.

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: Otavio, se a resposta do Rafael ajudou/resolveu, por favor, marque a resposta como ideal. :)

Answer (score 1):

O seu endereço esta incorreto. O padrao de url dos app services sao:

http://nomedoSite.azurewebsites.net.

No seu caso a url correta seria: https://acelerasp.azurewebsites.net/api/Ocorrencia/InserirOcorrencia

O Padrao: http://nomedoSite.scm.azurewebsites.net sao para tarefas administrativas como acesso a ambiente e arquivos do host.

Espero ter ajudado.